# Access icon resources through URI VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a WPF VB.NET application and I want to use an icon embedded in the applications resources as a menu icon. So far I have this code (in the window's initialized event):

```
MenuItem.Icon = New Image() With {.Source = New BitmapImage(New
Uri("Resources\Icon.ico", UriKind.Relative))}
```

And the icon is still not displayed, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your URI. If you set it in code behind, you must write the full [WPF Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx). You must also set the [Build Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx)
 of the icon file to `Resource` (the default value for icons is `None`).

```
MenuItem.Icon = New Image() With
{
    .Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Icon.ico"))
}
```

---

When you specify the URI in XAML, the default ImageSource TypeConverter will add the `pack://application:,,,` part, and you could simply write

```
<Image Source="/Resources/Icon.ico"/>
```

Comment: Thanks that helped lots! One thing I found, that when I was trying to embed the Icon using XAML, I had to add the pack://application:,,,. Is there anyway I can make sure that I don't have to use add it next time?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, in XAML you don't need to prepend the `pack://application:,,,` part.

Answer (score 0):

Better option is building menu in XAML:

1. Create folder `Images` in your solution
2. Add image as `Resources` to `Images` directory (in my sample code: "Icon.ico")
3. In XAML you can use following code:

...

```
<MenuItem Header="Item1">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="/Images/Icon.ico" Width="20" Height="20" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Or if you want to do this in code-behind you can use following code instead of step 3:

```
MenuItem.Icon = New Image() With {.Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri("/Images/Icon.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))}
```